# Is there a Star Wars book that explains the beginnings of the Jedi/Sith relationship?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a Star Wars book that explains the beginning of the Star Wars universe, or a good backstory about the origins of Jedi/Sith relationship?

Answer (score 8):

There is a comic,  that is now legends that proposes an origin:

[Star Wars: Dawn of the Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dawn_of_the_Jedi)

> "On the planet Tython, in the center of the galaxy, an order of warrior monks strives to maintain peace and to balance the mysterious power known as the Force. But a stranger is coming—one who will destroy both peace and balance, and open the galaxy to exploration and conquest. This is where it all begins!"
>   ― [Publisher's summary of Dawn of the Jedi: Force Storm 1](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/18-026/Star-Wars-Dawn-of-the-Jedi-1-Jan-Duursema-cover)

I know of nothing from Disney Canon though.

Comment: If you're looking for strictly a novel, there is Dawn of the Jedi: Into the Void. But the comics give more of a background.

Comment: @imerchant that would be a good answer,  and more preferable if the OP is after a book answer.

Answer (score 1):

The origins of the [Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith) lies at the beginning of the [Hundred-Year Darkness](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hundred-Year_Darkness):

> Thousands of years ago, a rogue Jedi had come to the understanding that the true power of the Force lay not through contemplation and passivity. Only by tapping its dark side could its true potential be gained. The Jedi Council at the time balked at this new direction. The dark Jedi was outcast, but he eventually gained followers to his new order.

The source for this comes from the Sith [entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20140611233856/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/sith/) in the *Star Wars Encyclopedia*, the official Star Wars public database of approved canon. It is correct as of 1 July 2014, when the Encyclopedia was shut down to be replaced by the Star Wars Databank.

Personally, I feel that the canonicity of the above origins is debatable:

- Wookieepedia says:

> The Encyclopedia entries only contained information available from the six Star Wars films and The Clone Wars series, and did not incorporate any Expanded Universe material.

- The previous statement is unsupported, but if true then the aforementioned origins of the Sith is G/T-Canon and definitely Disney canon, therefore overriding any Sith origins in the EU that is C-Canon/Legends
- The Legends restructure was effected on 25 April 2014. The Encyclopedia was established on 13 September 2011. The publication date of the above Sith origins is unknown.
- Most crucially, the new and latest Star Wars Databank does not contain the above Sith origins. It appears to have been "lost to history".

Whether the given origins are canon or Legends will hinge heavily on whether anyone can determine where in the movies or The Clone Wars series (both of which are Disney canon, and from which it is purportedly sourced from ultimately) it is found.

Comment: If you search for all archived copies of http://www.starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/sith/ on archive.org you can see that the earliest archived version of that page [dates to 25 September 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110925054918/http://www.starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/sith/), well before the new Disney canon was established.

Comment: @Hypnosifl That may be so, but the Encyclopedia is a database, not unlike Wookiepedia. The origin of all content in the Encyclopedia is purportedly only the movies and The Clone Wars - in other words only material that will eventually be accepted as Disney canon. This needs verification, and the ultimate source of the Sith origins given needs identification too.

Comment: Well, we only have some wookieepedia editor's word on that, they may have jumped to that conclusion because they only saw characters and worlds that had been featured in either the movies or The Clone Wars.

Comment: I got into a discussion about this on the [talk page for the wookieepedia entry about the Encyclopedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Encyclopedia_(StarWars.com)#Only_based_on_movies_and_The_Clone_Wars.3F), with a wookieepedia editor who seemed knowledgeable about why they had decided to treat the Encyclopedia info as canon. It seems this info about the origin of the Sith was never directly presented in the movies or The Clone Wars, but there is some circumstantial evidence that it was added in consultation with the creators behind The Clone Wars, and it wasn't from the EU.